# Build failed: Your build exceed the maximum build time of 120 minutes

Tags: stack-overflow

I am getting below error in build creation on expo.Please help here.
"Build failed: Your build exceeded the maximum build time of 120 minutes. On expo getting same issue"

{
"name": "grow-girl-app",
"version": "1.0.0",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
"eas:submit:all:production": "eas build --profile production --platform all --auto-submit",
"eas:submit:ios:production": "eas build --profile production --platform ios --auto-submit",
"eas:submit:ios:staging": "eas build --profile staging --platform ios --auto-submit",
"eas:submit:android:production": "eas build --profile production --platform android --auto-submit",
"eas:submit:android:staging": "eas build --profile staging --platform android --auto-submit",
"eas:build-android:staging": "eas build --profile staging --platform android",
"eas:build-android:production": "eas build --profile production --platform android",
"eas:build-android:production:apk": "eas build --profile production-apk --platform android",
"eas:simulator:build": "eas build -p ios --profile development-simulator",
"eas:emulator:build": "eas build -p android --profile development-simulator",
"eas:simulator:run": "eas build:run -p ios --latest",
"eas:emulator:run": "eas build:run -p android --latest",
"eas:device:build": "eas build -p ios --profile development-device",
"eas:device:android:build": "eas build -p android --profile development-device",
"eas:update:production": "eas update --channel production --auto",
"eas:update:staging": "eas update --channel staging --auto",
"type-check": "tsc -p tsconfig.json --noEmit",
"lint": "eslint . --ext .ts,.tsx",
"android": "expo run:android",
"ios": "expo run:ios",
"start": "expo start --dev-client",
"codegen": "graphql-codegen --config codegen.ts -r dotenv/config"
},
"dependencies": {
"@apollo/client": "^3.7.16",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from": "^7.18.9",
"@cloudinary/react": "^1.11.2",
"@cloudinary/url-gen": "^1.10.2",
"@expo/html-elements": "^0.5.1",
"@expo/react-native-action-sheet": "^4.0.1",
"@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.18.2",
"@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "7.2.0",
"@react-native-community/netinfo": "9.3.10",
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^18.4.0",
"@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "^18.4.0",
"@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^18.6.0",
"@react-native-firebase/perf": "^18.4.0",
"@redux-saga/is": "^1.1.3",
"@sentry/react-native": "5.10.0",
"@stytch/react-native": "^0.10.4",
"@stytch/react-native-inappbrowser-reborn": "^3.7.2",
"@tamagui/animations-react-native": "^1.26.1",
"@tamagui/babel-plugin": "^1.26.1",
"@tamagui/card": "^1.82.9",
"@tamagui/config": "^1.26.1",
"@tamagui/font-inter": "^1.26.1",
"@tamagui/theme-base": "^1.26.1",
"@types/firebase": "^3.2.1",
"@types/react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.14",
"@vercel/blob": "^0.22.1",
"apollo3-cache-persist": "^0.14.1",
"babel-plugin-transform-inline-environment-variables": "^0.4.4",
"convert": "^4.13.1",
"d3-shape": "^3.2.0",
"dayjs": "^1.11.9",
"expo": "~49.0.6",
"expo-application": "~5.3.0",
"expo-av": "~13.4.1",
"expo-build-properties": "^0.8.3",
"expo-camera": "~13.4.2",
"expo-constants": "~14.4.2",
"expo-dev-client": "~2.4.6",
"expo-device": "~5.4.0",
"expo-font": "~11.4.0",
"expo-image": "~1.3.4",
"expo-image-manipulator": "~11.3.0",
"expo-image-picker": "~14.3.2",
"expo-linear-gradient": "~12.3.0",
"expo-linking": "~5.0.2",
"expo-router": "2.0.0",
"expo-secure-store": "~12.3.1",
"expo-sharing": "~11.5.0",
"expo-splash-screen": "~0.20.5",
"expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
"expo-system-ui": "~2.4.0",
"expo-task-manager": "^11.5.0",
"expo-updates": "~0.18.19",
"firebase": "^10.5.2",
"graphql": "^16.7.1",
"moment": "^2.29.4",
"prettier-config-planes": "^1.0.1",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"react-hook-form": "^7.44.2",
"react-native": "0.72.6",
"react-native-actionsheet": "^2.4.2",
"react-native-btr": "^2.2.0",
"react-native-calendars": "^1.1304.1",
"react-native-element-dropdown": "^2.10.1",
"react-native-email-link": "^1.14.7",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
"react-native-masked-text": "^1.13.0",
"react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
"react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^17.0.0",
"react-native-pager-view": "6.2.0",
"react-native-purchases": "^6.2.3",
"react-native-reanimated": "~3.3.0",
"react-native-reanimated-carousel": "^3.3.2",
"react-native-root-toast": "^3.4.1",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
"react-native-screens": "~3.22.0",
"react-native-svg": "13.9.0",
"react-native-tab-view": "^3.5.2",
"react-native-uuid": "^2.0.1",
"react-native-video": "^5.2.1",
"react-native-view-shot": "3.7.0",
"react-native-web": "~0.19.6",
"react-native-webview": "13.2.2",
"reactotron-react-native": "^5.0.3",
"reactotron-redux": "^3.1.3",
"reactotron-redux-saga": "^4.2.3",
"redux-saga": "^1.2.3",
"tamagui": "^1.39.8",
"uuid": "3.4.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
"@datocms/cma-client-node": "^2.0.0",
"@esbuild-kit/esm-loader": "^2.6.5",
"@types/d3-shape": "^3.1.1",
"@types/react-native-actionsheet": "^2.4.3",
"@types/react-native-video": "^5.0.16",
"eslint": "^8.2.0",
"eslint-config-planes": "^3.1.1",
"prettier-config-planes": "^1.0.1",
"prop-types": "^15.8.1",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"ts-node": "^10.9.2"
},
"private": true
}
I just removed other dependency which is not used for app .